# download document via href from local path

Tags: html

I have a downloaded html document

**index.html** -- *main document*

**mail/4294967384.eml** -- *folder with file*

In index.html I have a link.

```
<a download href="./mail/4294967384.eml" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

When I click to link it's open new tab with url

**file:///C:/....mail/4294967384.eml**

rather than download file.
It there whay to fix it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3pksbd?file=index.html)

The folder structure:

- Index.html - at root
- 4294967384.eml - is in `mail` folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Download" />
    <script>
      function download(file) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        var fileContent = 'Insert Content';
        var myFile = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'eml' });
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        element.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile));
        element.setAttribute('download', file);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
      }

      document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener(
        'click',
        function() {
          var filename = '4294967384.eml';
          download(filename);
        },
        false
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var fileContent = 'Insert Content';` — The content is a file, no a string … and there's no way to get it into a string because the browser has no mechanism for JavaScript to read a file from the user's local disk without the user picking that file explicitly with a file input.

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute doesn't work across origins.

Your URL `file:///C:/....` is a local file which is *always* treated as a different origin.

… and since it is a local file it has effectively been downloaded already.

---

Your code should work fine it you host the website on an HTTP server.

Comment: but I'm looking for solution make it work when index.html is downloaded already to user's pc. (like offline mode)

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: what if i move from url to blob:  or data: schemes?

Comment: Might work, but you'd be embedded the entire file inside the HTML instead of reading an external file (which is what your question asks for)